# Rails - How to do If and else statements in a text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do a if and else statement in this text field with the value:

```
<%= f.text_field :rating, :size => 1, :min => 1, :max => 6, :value => if vind.ratings == 0 else vind.rating_score/vind.ratings, :type => 'range', :step => '1', :id => "#{vind.id}" %>
```

I get this error in view:

```
SyntaxError in Kategoris#show

Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/kategoris/_rating.html.erb where line #3 raised:

C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/kategoris/_rating.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
...ue => if vind.ratings == 0 else vind.rating_score/vind.ratin...
...                               ^
C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/kategoris/_rating.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...vind.rating_score/vind.ratings, :type => 'range', :step => '...
...                               ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use the shorthand, like this:

```
:value => ( vind.ratings == 0 ? 0 : vind.rating_score/vind.ratings )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= f.text_field :rating, :size => 1, :min => 1, :max => 6, :value => (vind.ratings == 0) ? 0 : vind.rating_score/vind.ratings, :type => 'range', :step => '1', :id => "#{vind.id}" %>
```

Which ends up looking like this for :value.

```
 :value => (vind.ratings == 0) ? 0 : vind.rating_score/vind.ratings
```

Comment: This is ruby code, but ruby works in rails as well. Rails was built on ruby.

Comment: Why cant I write if vind.ratings == 0 else 1 end or :value => "#{<% if vind.ratings == 0 %><% else %><%= vind.ratings %>}" ?

Comment: @tzown you can't write that simply because it's not valid ruby code

Comment: First off, your logic is wrong. You are stating If vid.ratings == 0 {do_nothing} else show vind.ratings. You can't do nothing in ruby. That is invalid code. You would just have to do if vind.ratings > 0 then show vind.ratings.

Comment: @tzown, for future reference what I am using is called Ternary Operators.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Ruby

Answer (score 0):

I can do like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :rating, :size => 1, :min => 1, :max => 6, :value => "#{if vind.ratings == 0 else vind.rating_score/vind.ratings, :type => 'range', :step => '1', :id => "#{vind.id}" %>
```

or like above but in ():

```
<%= f.text_field :rating, :size => 1, :min => 1, :max => 6, :value => ((vind.ratings == 0) ? value_here : vind.rating_score/vind.ratings), :type => 'range', :step => '1', :id => "#{vind.id}" %>
```